# What does "Cannot read property '_dirty' of undefined" mean? (Enchant.js/Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game using the 'Enchant.js' javascript framework for a college project and have received this error (Which causes the game to freeze). I don't even know what '_dirty' means and am completely out of my depth, methinks. (I googled '_dirty' and understand that it refers to 'unsaved changes' but am not entirely sure what it means by that.)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var Meds = Class.create(Sprite,
{
    //Two argument constructor takes in X and Y co-ordinate for patient
    initialize: function(x,y)
    {
        //Inherit all enchant.Sprite properties using it's constructor
        Sprite.apply(this, [16,16]);
        //Set image and co-ordinates for meds
        this.image = Game.instance.assets['art/icon0.gif'];
        this.frame = 13;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        //Add medicine to 'scene' group
        scene.addChild(this);
    },
    //Function for removing medicine
    remove: function()
    {
        //Remove from 'scene' group 
        scene.removeChild(this);
        //Delete med from array
        delete meds[this.key];
        //Delete med from memory
        delete this;
        //Decrement counter variable
        currentMedAmount--;
    }
});


game.rootScene.addEventListener('enterframe', function()
{
    for(var i=0; i < meds.length; i++)
    {
        if(sally.within(meds[i], 35) && game.input.Z_BUTTON)
        {
            meds[i].remove();
            console.log('WORKING!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It means that some code is trying use the string "_dirty" to reference a property via a reference that's not really a reference. Something like `foo._dirty` or `foo[key]` where "key" is "_dirty", and where "foo" is undefined.  Why? 1000 possibilities.

Comment: If the error is coming from inside the framework, use an un-minified version so that it's easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but I'm not using the minified version, and the phrase '_dirty' isn't anywhere in my code, nor do I have any references to 'undefined' objects (As far as I can tell.) I have referred to everything in the code in other places with no error at all, which leaves me at quite a loss as to what to do.

Comment: The browser developer tools should show you a stack trace associated with the error. That'll help figure out what's going on. The problem is likely to be something in the way your code does things that the library doesn't expect. Most JavaScript browser-oriented libraries have very little error-checking code, so when something goes wrong you don't get a clear explanation.

Comment: Note that the Enchant.js code uses the property name "_dirty" all over the place.

Comment: Again, thanks for the help. I'll keep tinkering away!

Comment: I managed to isolate the error (It happens whenever I try to delete the object from the array) but I still can't figure out why. I can 'removeChild()' but if I try to 'delete' using the same reference, i get the '_dirty' error. If I print to console, the obkect is not undefined, only when I try to delete it from the array.